# Javascript Generic For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, generics, for-loop, javascript-objects

Is there any way to create a generic for loop that will loop through either an array or an object correctly? I know I can write the following for loop, but it will also loop through other properties that would be added to an array.

```
for (item in x) {
   console.log(item)
}
```

By this I mean a for loop that will iterate:

```
x = [1, 2]
x.foo = "foo"
y = {first:1, second: 2}
```

x as

```
1
2
```

y as

```
first
second
```

The reason behind this is that I won't know until runtime what x will be (either an Array or an Object). Is my only option to create a function that will check at runtime?

Comment: If you don't know what type you're dealing with, you should try to put yourself in a position where you know the type of what you're dealing with. It's the easiest way to prevent manslaughter by coworker.

Comment: I definitely agree with your comment. Clarity is always to be desired. The reason for the ambiguity is I'm writing a compiler for a dynamic language that compiles into Javascript. As such, I don't necessarily know the type of whatever the source of the loop is so I needed a generic way of creating a for loop that would work at runtime.

Comment: In JS everything is an Object.. so in your case it might be wiser to treat arrays and even functions as objects because there is no real difference. In your example above `x = [1, 2]; x.foo = "foo";` Object.keys(x) will list you `["0", "1", "foo"]` but his won't show you the `length` property which is non enumerable. In some cases you may choose to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x);` and this will return all own properties regardless they are enumerable or not like `["0", "1", "length", "foo"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [for..of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

## Iterating over arrays

```
const array = [1, 2];
array.foo = "test";
for (const number of array) {
    console.log(number); // skips array.foo
}
```

## Iterating over objects

```
const object = {
    some: "string",
    number: 42
};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Anyway, from a code-style point of view, you should still check whether your object is an array before you iterate over it. You can use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to achieve that. So, assuming `data` is either an object or an array:

```
if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    for (const element of data) {
        // Iterate over array
    }
}
else {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        // Iterate over object
    }
}
```

## Generic looping

Since in JavaScript, `typeof [] === "object"` (i. e. arrays are objects that use the element's index as its key), you could reduce it to a **single loop** with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    // For arrays, `key` will be the index
}
```

Beware though that this latter method will not do justice to your exclusion of dynamic properties (e. g. `array.foo`), as you'll iterate over the result of `Object.entries`. If you *do* need to make this exclusion, use two `for..of` loops with `Array.isArray` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the index/key values you need as per your expected output, here's a simple one-liner.

```
function loop(x) {
  return (Array.isArray(x) ? x : Object.keys(x)).forEach(el => console.log(el));
}

loop(x); // 1 2
loop(y); // First Second
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t7xpeedj/3/)